# Parsing and getting data from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, api

I have a json from site https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&outputsize=full&apikey=demo

It looks like

```
{
"Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
    "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2018-07-03",
    "4. Output Size": "Full size",
    "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2018-07-03": {
        "1. open": "100.4800",
        "2. high": "100.6300",
        "3. low": "98.9400",
        "4. close": "99.0500",
        "5. volume": "14670275"
    },
    "2018-07-02": {
        "1. open": "98.1000",
        "2. high": "100.0600",
        "3. low": "98.0000",
        "4. close": "100.0100",
        "5. volume": "19564521"
    }
}
}
```

You can see in "Time Series (Daily)" there are different date objects. I want to access all the keys in each date and want to put data in array. I am using javascript and have no idea how to iterate through these different dates.

```
        console.log(data['TimeSeries (Daily)']['2018-07-03']);
```

This is how i accessed date, but this is single date i want to iterate through each.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the output you want

```
var tSeries=data['Time Series (Daily)'];
for(var tempData in tSeries)
{   
    console.log(tSeries[tempData]);
    console.log(tSeries[tempData]['1. open']);
    console.log(tSeries[tempData]['2. high']);
}
```

**Update**

If you need to access dates and wants them in separate Array

```
var tempDataStore = [];
var tSeries=data['Time Series (Daily)'];
for(var tempData in tSeries)
{   
    // Here You get your Date
    console.log("Your Date - " + tempData);
    console.log(tSeries[tempData]);
    console.log(tSeries[tempData]['1. open']);
    console.log(tSeries[tempData]['2. high']);
    tempDataStore.push({"Date":tempData,"open":tSeries[tempData]['1. open']})
}

console.log(tempDataStore)
```

Comment: Awesome, Upvoted, one more thing can we access dates (e.g 2018-07-02) in body of loop?
acctually I want to put all data (date, open,high,low,close) in array for each object.

Comment: @curious_nustian please check updated answer is it something you want?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a modern JavaScript engine, or a transpiler like [`babel`](https://babeljs.io/) this is cleanly done with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
Object.values(myData["Time Series (Daily)"]).forEach(function (date) {
  Object.entries(date).forEach(function([period, value]) {
    console.log(period, ':', value);
  })
})
```

This would log the following in your console:

```
1. open : 100.4800
2. high : 100.6300
3. low : 98.9400
// ....
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vj6dzk8h/8/)

Comment: How I will populate array from this, like I want to basically draw chart, (candlestick) which accepts data like this. 
`[
      ['Mon', 20, 28, 38, 45],
      ['Tue', 31, 38, 55, 66],
      ['Wed', 50, 55, 77, 80],
      ['Thu', 77, 77, 66, 50],
      ['Fri', 68, 66, 22, 15]
    ]`

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the keys of the "TimeSeries (Daily)" object. For example,

```
for(date in obj) {
    console.log(obj[date]);
}
```

To access the data in each date, just add another loop.

Comment: can you elaborate first line pls?
d = data['TimeSeries (Daily)'];
you mean this?

Comment: Yup, `let date in data['TimeSeries (Daily)']`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for in loop to get desired output

```
let myList = data['TimeSeries (Daily)'];
for (var index in myList) 
{
    console.log(myList[index]);
}
```

Regards

Comment: Wrong.! code.. correct this line console.log(myList[index]);

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this is what you are looking for:

```js
data = {
"Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
    "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2018-07-03",
    "4. Output Size": "Full size",
    "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2018-07-03": {
        "1. open": "100.4800",
        "2. high": "100.6300",
        "3. low": "98.9400",
        "4. close": "99.0500",
        "5. volume": "14670275"
    },
    "2018-07-02": {
        "1. open": "98.1000",
        "2. high": "100.0600",
        "3. low": "98.0000",
        "4. close": "100.0100",
        "5. volume": "19564521"
    }
}
}


Object.keys(data["Time Series (Daily)"]).forEach(date => console.log(date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is easiest way to do this...

```
const response = await fetch('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&outputsize=full&apikey=demo');
const responseData = await response.json();
let allTimeStamps = [];
let allTimeStampsData = [];
for(let key in responseData["Time Series (Daily)"]){
    allTimeStamps.push(key);
    allTimeStampsData.push(responseData["Time Series (Daily)"][key]);
}
console.log("seperatedData", {allTimeStamps, allTimeStampsData});
```

try in the same domain to prevent cross-origin issue

Comment: @curious_nustian My bad havent noticed that last line Please find the updated edit