# Reading historical data json in swift using SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json, alpha-vantage

I am trying to store historical price data for a stock in an array from the JSON format it is returned in by the Alpha Vantage API. I am not sure how to do that each node will be a specific date and time.
This question: [Parsing and getting data from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176519/parsing-and-getting-data-from-json) has essentially the same question but the original poster is not using swift so I am still unable to convert that code to be usable in my program.
This is an example of what the JSON I recieve from Alpha Vantage looks like:

```
{
    "Meta Data" =     {
        "1. Information" = "Intraday (5min) open, high, low, close prices and volume";
        "2. Symbol" = MSFT;
        "3. Last Refreshed" = "2019-07-23 16:00:00";
        "4. Interval" = 5min;
        "5. Output Size" = Compact;
        "6. Time Zone" = "US/Eastern";
    };
    "Time Series (5min)" =     {
        "2019-07-22 14:15:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.2554";
            "2. high" = "138.2700";
            "3. low" = "138.1600";
            "4. close" = "138.2368";
            "5. volume" = 172939;
        };
        "2019-07-22 14:20:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.2300";
            "2. high" = "138.2600";
            "3. low" = "138.1800";
            "4. close" = "138.1950";
            "5. volume" = 100154;
        };
        "2019-07-22 14:25:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.1900";
            "2. high" = "138.2200";
            "3. low" = "138.1800";
            "4. close" = "138.1950";
            "5. volume" = 87335;
        };
        "2019-07-22 14:30:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.1900";
            "2. high" = "138.2200";
            "3. low" = "138.1777";
            "4. close" = "138.1850";
            "5. volume" = 93773;
        };
        "2019-07-22 14:35:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.1854";
            "2. high" = "138.2800";
            "3. low" = "138.1600";
            "4. close" = "138.2600";
            "5. volume" = 152923;
        };
        "2019-07-22 14:40:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.2500";
            "2. high" = "138.2750";
            "3. low" = "138.1200";
            "4. close" = "138.1500";
            "5. volume" = 115094;
        };
        "2019-07-22 14:45:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.1500";
            "2. high" = "138.2400";
            "3. low" = "138.1400";
            "4. close" = "138.2100";
            "5. volume" = 71032;
        };
        "2019-07-22 14:50:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.2101";
            "2. high" = "138.3500";
            "3. low" = "138.2060";
            "4. close" = "138.3450";
            "5. volume" = 125469;
        };
        "2019-07-22 14:55:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.3500";
            "2. high" = "138.4200";
            "3. low" = "138.3400";
            "4. close" = "138.4100";
            "5. volume" = 118987;
        };
        "2019-07-22 15:00:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.4100";
            "2. high" = "138.4700";
            "3. low" = "138.3900";
            "4. close" = "138.4500";
            "5. volume" = 115974;
        };
        "2019-07-22 15:05:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.4450";
            "2. high" = "138.8000";
            "3. low" = "138.4350";
            "4. close" = "138.7050";
            "5. volume" = 404897;
        };
        "2019-07-22 15:10:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.7050";
            "2. high" = "138.7900";
            "3. low" = "138.6650";
            "4. close" = "138.6800";
            "5. volume" = 166921;
        };
        "2019-07-22 15:15:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.6800";
            "2. high" = "138.6850";
            "3. low" = "138.5300";
            "4. close" = "138.5700";
            "5. volume" = 169380;
        };
        "2019-07-22 15:20:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.5700";
            "2. high" = "138.6700";
            "3. low" = "138.5500";
            "4. close" = "138.6300";
            "5. volume" = 161121;
        };
        "2019-07-22 15:25:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.6300";
            "2. high" = "138.6500";
            "3. low" = "138.4100";
            "4. close" = "138.4600";
            "5. volume" = 183601;
        };
        "2019-07-22 15:30:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.4600";
            "2. high" = "138.4700";
            "3. low" = "138.4000";
            "4. close" = "138.4500";
            "5. volume" = 135392;
        };
        "2019-07-22 15:35:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.4430";
            "2. high" = "138.4568";
            "3. low" = "138.2950";
            "4. close" = "138.3400";
            "5. volume" = 210479;
        };
        "2019-07-22 15:40:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.3400";
            "2. high" = "138.4000";
            "3. low" = "138.3300";
            "4. close" = "138.3650";
            "5. volume" = 249061;
        };
        "2019-07-22 15:45:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.3600";
            "2. high" = "138.4700";
            "3. low" = "138.3350";
            "4. close" = "138.3850";
            "5. volume" = 233272;
        };
        "2019-07-22 15:50:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.3750";
            "2. high" = "138.4550";
            "3. low" = "138.3400";
            "4. close" = "138.4400";
            "5. volume" = 252689;
        };
        "2019-07-22 15:55:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.4400";
            "2. high" = "138.4900";
            "3. low" = "138.3500";
            "4. close" = "138.4400";
            "5. volume" = 321964;
        };
        "2019-07-22 16:00:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.4400";
            "2. high" = "138.5500";
            "3. low" = "138.3400";
            "4. close" = "138.4300";
            "5. volume" = 886466;
        };
        "2019-07-23 09:35:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "139.7600";
            "2. high" = "139.9900";
            "3. low" = "139.1400";
            "4. close" = "139.1585";
            "5. volume" = 1448602;
        };
        "2019-07-23 09:40:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "139.1500";
            "2. high" = "139.1700";
            "3. low" = "138.7600";
            "4. close" = "138.7900";
            "5. volume" = 486915;
        };
        "2019-07-23 09:45:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.7800";
            "2. high" = "138.7800";
            "3. low" = "138.5300";
            "4. close" = "138.6100";
            "5. volume" = 442437;
        };
        "2019-07-23 09:50:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.5900";
            "2. high" = "138.6600";
            "3. low" = "138.3928";
            "4. close" = "138.4700";
            "5. volume" = 486548;
        };
        "2019-07-23 09:55:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.4700";
            "2. high" = "138.4800";
            "3. low" = "138.1500";
            "4. close" = "138.3384";
            "5. volume" = 315070;
        };
        "2019-07-23 10:00:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.3500";
            "2. high" = "138.3650";
            "3. low" = "138.1700";
            "4. close" = "138.2600";
            "5. volume" = 311972;
        };
        "2019-07-23 10:05:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.2550";
            "2. high" = "138.4900";
            "3. low" = "138.2500";
            "4. close" = "138.4600";
            "5. volume" = 331242;
        };
        "2019-07-23 10:10:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.4600";
            "2. high" = "138.6000";
            "3. low" = "138.2200";
            "4. close" = "138.2550";
            "5. volume" = 301482;
        };
        "2019-07-23 10:15:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.2400";
            "2. high" = "138.2600";
            "3. low" = "138.1200";
            "4. close" = "138.1200";
            "5. volume" = 239667;
        };
        "2019-07-23 10:20:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.1133";
            "2. high" = "138.1750";
            "3. low" = "138.0300";
            "4. close" = "138.1600";
            "5. volume" = 257073;
        };
        "2019-07-23 10:25:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.1600";
            "2. high" = "138.2200";
            "3. low" = "138.0815";
            "4. close" = "138.2025";
            "5. volume" = 231030;
        };
        "2019-07-23 10:30:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.2000";
            "2. high" = "138.3700";
            "3. low" = "138.1750";
            "4. close" = "138.3200";
            "5. volume" = 224853;
        };
        "2019-07-23 10:35:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.3285";
            "2. high" = "138.6240";
            "3. low" = "138.2900";
            "4. close" = "138.6100";
            "5. volume" = 160456;
        };
        "2019-07-23 10:40:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.6100";
            "2. high" = "138.6888";
            "3. low" = "138.5800";
            "4. close" = "138.6850";
            "5. volume" = 200947;
        };
        "2019-07-23 10:45:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.6900";
            "2. high" = "138.7700";
            "3. low" = "138.6600";
            "4. close" = "138.7350";
            "5. volume" = 177645;
        };
        "2019-07-23 10:50:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.7300";
            "2. high" = "138.7800";
            "3. low" = "138.6610";
            "4. close" = "138.6950";
            "5. volume" = 172413;
        };
        "2019-07-23 10:55:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.6920";
            "2. high" = "138.7500";
            "3. low" = "138.6701";
            "4. close" = "138.7200";
            "5. volume" = 132333;
        };
        "2019-07-23 11:00:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.7249";
            "2. high" = "138.9700";
            "3. low" = "138.7249";
            "4. close" = "138.8500";
            "5. volume" = 177519;
        };
        "2019-07-23 11:05:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.8500";
            "2. high" = "138.8650";
            "3. low" = "138.6400";
            "4. close" = "138.6550";
            "5. volume" = 176238;
        };
        "2019-07-23 11:10:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.6750";
            "2. high" = "138.7100";
            "3. low" = "138.5800";
            "4. close" = "138.6806";
            "5. volume" = 134367;
        };
        "2019-07-23 11:15:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.6800";
            "2. high" = "138.8200";
            "3. low" = "138.6800";
            "4. close" = "138.7850";
            "5. volume" = 110527;
        };
        "2019-07-23 11:20:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.7900";
            "2. high" = "138.8194";
            "3. low" = "138.7500";
            "4. close" = "138.7933";
            "5. volume" = 118086;
        };
        "2019-07-23 11:25:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.7900";
            "2. high" = "138.9400";
            "3. low" = "138.7750";
            "4. close" = "138.9300";
            "5. volume" = 141666;
        };
        "2019-07-23 11:30:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.9400";
            "2. high" = "138.9400";
            "3. low" = "138.7500";
            "4. close" = "138.7650";
            "5. volume" = 188070;
        };
        "2019-07-23 11:35:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.7647";
            "2. high" = "138.7700";
            "3. low" = "138.6100";
            "4. close" = "138.6300";
            "5. volume" = 170608;
        };
        "2019-07-23 11:40:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.6300";
            "2. high" = "138.6600";
            "3. low" = "138.4600";
            "4. close" = "138.6200";
            "5. volume" = 182772;
        };
        "2019-07-23 11:45:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.6200";
            "2. high" = "138.6650";
            "3. low" = "138.5500";
            "4. close" = "138.6268";
            "5. volume" = 117356;
        };
        "2019-07-23 11:50:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.6250";
            "2. high" = "138.6500";
            "3. low" = "138.4700";
            "4. close" = "138.6100";
            "5. volume" = 138138;
        };
        "2019-07-23 11:55:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.6100";
            "2. high" = "138.6400";
            "3. low" = "138.5300";
            "4. close" = "138.5950";
            "5. volume" = 120127;
        };
        "2019-07-23 12:00:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.5900";
            "2. high" = "138.5900";
            "3. low" = "138.4600";
            "4. close" = "138.5650";
            "5. volume" = 132002;
        };
        "2019-07-23 12:05:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.5350";
            "2. high" = "138.5500";
            "3. low" = "138.2000";
            "4. close" = "138.3000";
            "5. volume" = 193996;
        };
        "2019-07-23 12:10:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.2800";
            "2. high" = "138.4300";
            "3. low" = "138.2301";
            "4. close" = "138.3550";
            "5. volume" = 149343;
        };
        "2019-07-23 12:15:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.3600";
            "2. high" = "138.3700";
            "3. low" = "138.2800";
            "4. close" = "138.2850";
            "5. volume" = 144719;
        };
        "2019-07-23 12:20:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.2850";
            "2. high" = "138.4699";
            "3. low" = "138.2800";
            "4. close" = "138.4400";
            "5. volume" = 119857;
        };
        "2019-07-23 12:25:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.4400";
            "2. high" = "138.5700";
            "3. low" = "138.4400";
            "4. close" = "138.4900";
            "5. volume" = 97856;
        };
        "2019-07-23 12:30:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.4803";
            "2. high" = "138.4900";
            "3. low" = "138.2400";
            "4. close" = "138.2999";
            "5. volume" = 150306;
        };
        "2019-07-23 12:35:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.2900";
            "2. high" = "138.4000";
            "3. low" = "138.2200";
            "4. close" = "138.3750";
            "5. volume" = 100281;
        };
        "2019-07-23 12:40:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.3700";
            "2. high" = "138.4500";
            "3. low" = "138.3500";
            "4. close" = "138.3800";
            "5. volume" = 64321;
        };
        "2019-07-23 12:45:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.3800";
            "2. high" = "138.4688";
            "3. low" = "138.3400";
            "4. close" = "138.4500";
            "5. volume" = 89711;
        };
        "2019-07-23 12:50:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.4550";
            "2. high" = "138.5700";
            "3. low" = "138.4400";
            "4. close" = "138.5700";
            "5. volume" = 98792;
        };
        "2019-07-23 12:55:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.5600";
            "2. high" = "138.6050";
            "3. low" = "138.4900";
            "4. close" = "138.5250";
            "5. volume" = 110434;
        };
        "2019-07-23 13:00:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.5300";
            "2. high" = "138.6050";
            "3. low" = "138.4900";
            "4. close" = "138.5600";
            "5. volume" = 119086;
        };
        "2019-07-23 13:05:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.5750";
            "2. high" = "138.5900";
            "3. low" = "138.5000";
            "4. close" = "138.5600";
            "5. volume" = 96423;
        };
        "2019-07-23 13:10:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.5700";
            "2. high" = "138.6800";
            "3. low" = "138.5700";
            "4. close" = "138.6300";
            "5. volume" = 108116;
        };
        "2019-07-23 13:15:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.6300";
            "2. high" = "138.6800";
            "3. low" = "138.5900";
            "4. close" = "138.6650";
            "5. volume" = 98901;
        };
        "2019-07-23 13:20:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.6700";
            "2. high" = "138.7300";
            "3. low" = "138.6300";
            "4. close" = "138.6700";
            "5. volume" = 82617;
        };
        "2019-07-23 13:25:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.6650";
            "2. high" = "138.7200";
            "3. low" = "138.6050";
            "4. close" = "138.6950";
            "5. volume" = 99808;
        };
        "2019-07-23 13:30:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.6950";
            "2. high" = "138.7450";
            "3. low" = "138.5700";
            "4. close" = "138.6247";
            "5. volume" = 121056;
        };
        "2019-07-23 13:35:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.6200";
            "2. high" = "138.6858";
            "3. low" = "138.6000";
            "4. close" = "138.6700";
            "5. volume" = 62346;
        };
        "2019-07-23 13:40:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.6600";
            "2. high" = "138.7000";
            "3. low" = "138.5900";
            "4. close" = "138.7000";
            "5. volume" = 91894;
        };
        "2019-07-23 13:45:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.6950";
            "2. high" = "139.0201";
            "3. low" = "138.6800";
            "4. close" = "138.8900";
            "5. volume" = 507782;
        };
        "2019-07-23 13:50:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.9000";
            "2. high" = "139.0200";
            "3. low" = "138.8800";
            "4. close" = "138.9132";
            "5. volume" = 189056;
        };
        "2019-07-23 13:55:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.9120";
            "2. high" = "138.9800";
            "3. low" = "138.8508";
            "4. close" = "138.9550";
            "5. volume" = 92105;
        };
        "2019-07-23 14:00:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.9550";
            "2. high" = "139.1300";
            "3. low" = "138.9550";
            "4. close" = "139.0700";
            "5. volume" = 323043;
        };
        "2019-07-23 14:05:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "139.1301";
            "2. high" = "139.1301";
            "3. low" = "138.9300";
            "4. close" = "139.0000";
            "5. volume" = 234585;
        };
        "2019-07-23 14:10:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.9900";
            "2. high" = "139.0200";
            "3. low" = "138.8700";
            "4. close" = "138.8700";
            "5. volume" = 98490;
        };
        "2019-07-23 14:15:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.8750";
            "2. high" = "138.9500";
            "3. low" = "138.8306";
            "4. close" = "138.9200";
            "5. volume" = 89289;
        };
        "2019-07-23 14:20:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.9250";
            "2. high" = "138.9700";
            "3. low" = "138.9000";
            "4. close" = "138.9104";
            "5. volume" = 82695;
        };
        "2019-07-23 14:25:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.9142";
            "2. high" = "138.9550";
            "3. low" = "138.8700";
            "4. close" = "138.8700";
            "5. volume" = 102547;
        };
        "2019-07-23 14:30:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.8700";
            "2. high" = "138.9000";
            "3. low" = "138.8300";
            "4. close" = "138.8759";
            "5. volume" = 64052;
        };
        "2019-07-23 14:35:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.8750";
            "2. high" = "138.9000";
            "3. low" = "138.8250";
            "4. close" = "138.8650";
            "5. volume" = 104288;
        };
        "2019-07-23 14:40:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.8700";
            "2. high" = "138.9500";
            "3. low" = "138.8500";
            "4. close" = "138.9200";
            "5. volume" = 112310;
        };
        "2019-07-23 14:45:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.9250";
            "2. high" = "139.0600";
            "3. low" = "138.9200";
            "4. close" = "139.0400";
            "5. volume" = 183068;
        };
        "2019-07-23 14:50:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "139.0500";
            "2. high" = "139.0900";
            "3. low" = "139.0100";
            "4. close" = "139.0400";
            "5. volume" = 154216;
        };
        "2019-07-23 14:55:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "139.0500";
            "2. high" = "139.1000";
            "3. low" = "139.0100";
            "4. close" = "139.0600";
            "5. volume" = 142960;
        };
        "2019-07-23 15:00:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "139.0750";
            "2. high" = "139.1484";
            "3. low" = "139.0500";
            "4. close" = "139.0900";
            "5. volume" = 130883;
        };
        "2019-07-23 15:05:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "139.0900";
            "2. high" = "139.1100";
            "3. low" = "138.9700";
            "4. close" = "138.9750";
            "5. volume" = 145883;
        };
        "2019-07-23 15:10:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.9800";
            "2. high" = "139.0590";
            "3. low" = "138.9550";
            "4. close" = "139.0300";
            "5. volume" = 212548;
        };
        "2019-07-23 15:15:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "139.0200";
            "2. high" = "139.0500";
            "3. low" = "138.9900";
            "4. close" = "139.0200";
            "5. volume" = 170454;
        };
        "2019-07-23 15:20:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "139.0200";
            "2. high" = "139.0400";
            "3. low" = "138.9300";
            "4. close" = "138.9750";
            "5. volume" = 274115;
        };
        "2019-07-23 15:25:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "138.9700";
            "2. high" = "139.0700";
            "3. low" = "138.9550";
            "4. close" = "139.0500";
            "5. volume" = 205326;
        };
        "2019-07-23 15:30:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "139.0550";
            "2. high" = "139.1400";
            "3. low" = "139.0229";
            "4. close" = "139.0599";
            "5. volume" = 186373;
        };
        "2019-07-23 15:35:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "139.0600";
            "2. high" = "139.2300";
            "3. low" = "139.0600";
            "4. close" = "139.1900";
            "5. volume" = 227178;
        };
        "2019-07-23 15:40:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "139.1900";
            "2. high" = "139.2150";
            "3. low" = "139.1100";
            "4. close" = "139.1150";
            "5. volume" = 177800;
        };
        "2019-07-23 15:45:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "139.1200";
            "2. high" = "139.1600";
            "3. low" = "139.0300";
            "4. close" = "139.1100";
            "5. volume" = 264300;
        };
        "2019-07-23 15:50:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "139.1050";
            "2. high" = "139.1750";
            "3. low" = "139.0800";
            "4. close" = "139.1337";
            "5. volume" = 266406;
        };
        "2019-07-23 15:55:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "139.1300";
            "2. high" = "139.2000";
            "3. low" = "139.1300";
            "4. close" = "139.1500";
            "5. volume" = 328592;
        };
        "2019-07-23 16:00:00" =         {
            "1. open" = "139.1500";
            "2. high" = "139.2900";
            "3. low" = "139.1200";
            "4. close" = "139.2800";
            "5. volume" = 576088;
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: There's no need for SwiftyJSON. Swift has the same functionality built in. Use `Codable`

Comment: @Adrian any pointers on how I would encode it using Codable? I am new to swift and have never used codable structs with JSONs before